# Cannot select active printer using Excel via pywin32

Tags: python, vba, pywin32, win32com

I have an issue when tried to print the Excel document with the specific printer (not just a default printer). Here the snippet of the code:

```
from win32com import client

excelApp = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application") book = excelApp.Workbooks.open(r"C:\\folder\\test.xlsx")

workSheet = book.Worksheets('Sheet1') workSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "test"
workSheet.PrintOut(ActivePrinter="MyPrinter on NE00:")
//the document still printed on default printer not on the printer supposed to be.

book.Save()
book.Close()
```

Actually, this issue doesn't happen on my development computer (did initially but was solved by installing `pywin32` from standalone, not from `pip`). However when I deploy the app on the Windows Server and use stand-alone `pywin32`, the issue still there, Windows Server still prints to the configured default printer.

Comment: Could be a permissions / privileges issue.